# How to arrange data in Excel from different worksheets?

Tags: excel

So I have data in different Excel documents, and I want to make a summary of data. I just count the number of data per each column and put that data in separate sheet. But in all the documents there is equal amount of same columns, just those columns are arranged in different order. How do I put everything in one document without manually rearranging?

Example: [image: Desc]

I put two datasheets from two documents which are not aligned, is there a way to make that automatically?

Comment: Use `.Find` to find the Headers in Row 1. Once you know which column is the relevant header in then you can copy it across. See [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) on how to use `.Find`

Comment: Thanks! I think I will do simplier approach and go with manual.

Comment: `Thanks! I think I will do simplier approach and go with manual.` Whatever rocks your boat ;)